# Android: how to set a proximity alert to fire only when exiting or only when entering the location

Tags: android, alert, locationmanager, proximity

I am developing a ToDo app with reminders(by time and by location) and the thing is I give the user the option to choose if he wants the reminder by location to alert when he is **entering** the location or when he **exits** the location.
how can i do that??

I know about the **KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING** but I dont know how to use it
Please help...
thanx in advance

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING is usually used to determine whether the device is entering or exiting.

You should first register to the LocationManager

```
LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Intent intent = new Intent(Constants.ACTION_PROXIMITY_ALERT);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, intent, 0);

locationManager.addProximityAlert(location.getLatitude(),
    location.getLongitude(), location.getRadius(), -1, pendingIntent);
```

The PendingIntent will be used to generate an Intent to fire when entry to or exit from the alert region is detected.
You should define a broadcast receiver to receive the broadcast sent from LocationManager:

```
public class YourReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        final String key = LocationManager.KEY_PROXIMITY_ENTERING;
        final Boolean entering = intent.getBooleanExtra(key, false);

        if (entering) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "entering", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(context, "exiting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Then register the receiver in your manifest.

```
<receiver android:name="yourpackage.YourReceiver " >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="ACTION_PROXIMITY_ALERT" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: Another question - my receiver already handles the **reminder by time** broadcast. how can I define which reminder fired the action? both of them are fired from the same class - @Jermaine Xu

Comment: BTW thnx for the answer regarding the main question. seems like this is the answer - @Jermaine Xu

Comment: I think you want intent.getAction(), don't you?

Comment: so inside the intent-filter attribute in the xml i need to have two <action> attributes? one for the **reminder by time** and one for the **reminder by location** ? @Jermaine Xu

Comment: how can i set the alert to go off only when i exit the location? must i use **location listener??** @Jermaine Xu

Comment: This answer is towards illustrating how to get informed when device approaching or exiting a region. So If you want to disable the alert, just put some code into the "else" region in the above sample. If you are wondering about how to show an alert, then you'd better ask another question.

Comment: found this: `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, MIN_TIME, MIN_DISTANCE, pendingIntent);`

Answer (score 0):

You can find a good example here:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/Core-Class/ProximityAlertDemo.htm